# How to get ValidationMessage in MVC View without HTML helper adding its own span?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

First off , I am new to MVC. I have a view which has the following line of code:

```
<span id="loginerror" style="border-color:red;"> @Html.ValidationMessage("UserName") </span>
```

This works fine except that it adds a span within my `loginerror` instead of just displaying the error within `loginerror` . I am aware that I can also add css through html helper but I would like to do it in this way if possible. I just want to get the value of ValidationMessage without having to change a lot of code.

Comment: You cant, unless you want to make a lot of modifications to the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file. But why do you think you need to do this. The plug adds class names, so you can just style the elements using css to display however you want (and the helper does not add any css, only class names).

Comment: @StephenMuecke I don't think I need to do this.  But I was just wondering if I could just get the value of error message without it adding its own span element. Perhaps it could give me more control. What if tomorrow if I want to display the error message in an existing <p>  tag?

Comment: Then wrap `@Html.ValidationMessage()` in `<p>` tags. Its not clear why you think you need to remove the inner span element.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Because I dont want redundant span? If I have to show message within a <p> why do I need span within <p>?

Comment: Then (1) Write your own `HtmlHelper` extension method to output the container placeholder and (2) modify the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file (and best of luck)

Comment: @StephenMuecke I realize that a couple of redundant span mean nothing. I was just curious if I can get the value of error without it inserting span. modifying unobtrusive.js is a no no for me. I may consider writing my own HtmlHelper method.. but I don't think it's worth it. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I though so :). But there is no reason to wrap it in a `<p>` element for example (then you are just adding redundant elements). You can use css to style the `<span>` to be whatever your want - make in `display: inline-block`, add some borders, margins, padding, color, alignment etc. Don't confuse behavior with appearance

Comment: @StephenMuecke duly noted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `@Html.ValidationMessage()` helper outputs a `<span>` element, which assuming the property is valid is

```
<span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="xxx" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span>
```

and if the property is invalid

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="xxx" data-valmsg-replace="true">Error message</span>
```

For client side validation, the `jquery.validate.js` and `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` files add an inner span for the error message which is

```
<span class="field-validation-error" data-valmsg-for="xxx" data-valmsg-replace="true">
    <span for="xxx" generated="true" class="">Error message</span>
</span>
```

In order to change this behavior, you would need to create your own `HtmlHelper` extension method for the outer `<span>` element or use `MVC-5` which has overloads that allow you to add a parameter specifying the `tag`.

However, for the inner span element generated by client side validation, you would need to modify the `jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js` file and it should be obvious that this is not something you would want to do.

Instead you can just create your own css file to style the default span elements, for example

```
field-validation-error {
    display: inline-block;
    border: solid 1px red;
    color: green;
    margin: 10px;
}
```